# clearTimeout() outside of function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this line of code, but it doesn't work, and I'm guessing that my function is the cause of the problem here. Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval;

    function move(ele) {
        $(ele).animate({
            'background-position-y': '0px'
        }, 200, function () {
            $(ele).animate({
                'background-position-y': '3px'
            }, 200, function () {
                interval = setTimeout(function () {
                    move(ele)
                }, 3);
            });
        });
    };
    $(".up").hover(function () {
        move(this), function () {
            clearTimeout(interval);
            interval = null;
            $(this).css("background-position", "80px 3px ");
        };
    });
```

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not properly closing your first function in the `hover` handler; instead, you have one nested inside the other.

Comment: I've voted to close because “This question is unlikely to help any future visitors; it is only relevant to … an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.”

Comment: The `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` attributes are not supported by Firefox.  Just in case it matters

Comment: @WizardofOgz thanks for pointing that out, it's definitely important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the proper closing braces as suggested by David there is still a problem which keeps the animation going.  Clearing the timer (interval) doesn't stop the callback functions passed to `.animate()` from executing.  So `interval = setTimeout(...)` will still get executed and perpetuated the animation cycle.

I reworked the code a bit for a working example, though there could be some improvements (like getting rid of a global variable).  http://jsfiddle.net/aKKRk/

Comment: Thank you, your solution fixed my problem.
I completely forgot that I can use true and false to check this.
This is why I don't like using timeouts and intervals.

Thanks a lot, once again.

Answer (score 1):

err, it looks like your *actual* problem is that you're only passing one function to `hover`, not two. You've got `….hover(function() { move(…), function() { … } })` instead of `….hover(function() { move(…); }, function() { … })`.

In the future, this kind of error will be much easier to spot if you make a habit of consistently indenting your code.

Comment: I did what you said, but clearTimeout doesn't work, the function still loops over and over.

Comment: Are you sure `clearTimeout` is actually being called? If you're not sure: use a debugger or logs or something to check. If it's not being called, please update your question with your new code.

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that, I'm using Chrome's inspect element option, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: UUuhh… Explain how to do what, exactly?

Comment: How to check if clearTimeout has been called or not. After searching for it in Google Chrome inspect element feature I've managed to find only something like this "ReferenceError: interval is not defined" but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try using the debugger, or log statements.

Comment: only thing that I've managed to dug up so far was clearTimeout(interval) unidentified;

Comment: Ah, ok — that probably means that the interval is undefined. It looks like that could happen if the `move` animations don't finish before `clearTimeout` is called.

Comment: You're up to something, after I've changed setTimeout from 3ms to 3000ms I can finally stop the setTimeout, but 3000ms isn't working out for me, so is there some other workaround?